# How to optimize a lot of gifs at the same time?

Tags: optimization, gif

my question refers to **gif optimization**.

I've used the main known softwares to achieve gif optimization, but each of them allows to optimize *one gif at the same time*.

Does someone know how to optimize **thousands of gifs** at the same time?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The OpenSource project, [ImageMagick](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ImageMagick), offers a suite of command-line tools for batch processing images.

Check out the article "[ImageMagick v6 Examples -- Animation Optimization](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/anim_opt/)" for a how-to on performing some GIF opimizations.